# No such DSL method 'folder'

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I have been trying to create a folder inside a Jenkins pipeline with the following code:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    node {
        label 'python'
    }
}
stages{
    stage('Folder'){
        steps{
            folder 'New Folder'
        }
    }
}
}
```

But I get the following error message
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'folder' found among steps

Jenkins already has installed the Cloudbees-Folder plugin so not sure why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudbees Folders Plugin is for creating folders in Jenkins to organize jobs. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin

Instead use the below to create directory

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'python' }
}
stages{
    stage('Folder'){
        steps{
            script 
            {
               dir('New Folder') {
                 sh 'pwd'
               }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for not being specific  but I do need to create a Jenkins folder as part of the pipeline.

Comment: You want to create a Jenkins project folder using your pipeline that is visible in the Jenkins UI view?

Comment: yes, so before we had a line like this of code that will do that for us"
step([$class: 'ExecuteDslScripts', scriptLocation: [scriptText: "folder('NewFolder')"], ignoreExisting: true])

but this doesn't work anymore. This is a very old job we are trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a little more I found that using the jobDSL mehtod will help me create the folders. Below is the code example.

```
    pipeline{

    agent { node { label 'python' } }

    stages{
        stage('Folder'){
            steps{
                jobDsl scriptText: "folder('New Folder')",
                    ignoreExisting: true
            }
        }//end of stage
    }//end of stages
}//end of pipeline
```